# AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'dayData'

Tags: python, pandas

I have some code that I am trying to implement on a df called `dayData`:

the head of the large dataframe `dayData` looks like:

```
            wave              sector  adjusted_ratio  my_long
date
2014-03-24   2.0  Telecommunications        0.998106      0.0
2014-03-24   2.0              Retail        1.000998      0.0
2014-03-24   2.0              Retail        0.996631      0.0
2014-03-24   2.0     Pharmaceuticals        1.000229      0.0
2014-03-24   2.0                Food        1.000304      0.0
```

`dayData` has the following column types and alias:

```
column name in df     type      alias
---------------------------------------------
wave               float64      COL_WAVE
sector             object       COL_SECTOR
adjusted_ratio     float64      COL_ADJ_RATIO
my_long            float64      COL_MYLONG
```

The below code is trying to group the dataframe where the `wave` is less than or equal to a `thresh` value and by `sector`.

The code trying to group the data:

```
waves = sorted(set(dayData[COL_WAVE]))[::-1]
dayData[COL_MYLONG] = np.nan
for thresh in waves:
    dayData[COL_MYLONG] = (dayData[dayData[COL_WAVE].le(thresh)].groupby(COL_SECTOR)
                   .dayData[COL_ADJ_RATIO].rank(ascending=False).sub(1)
                   .reindex(dayData.index)
                   .fillna(dayData[COL_MYLONG])
                )
```

I however get a error:

```
    dayData[COL_MYLONG] = (dayData[dayData[COL_WAVE].le(thresh)].groupby(COL_SECTOR)
  File "/home/vagrant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 580, in __getattr__
    f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{attr}'"
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'dayData'
```

Comment: It seems typo, change `.dayData[COL_ADJ_RATIO].rank(ascending=False).sub(1)` to `[COL_ADJ_RATIO].rank(ascending=False).sub(1)`

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.